# Select children link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, jquery-selectors

How should select the link `<a>` in this structure with jquery

```
<span id="guiaAtencion:ot4">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.apps.com">link</a>
  </p>
</span>
```

Comment: It all depends under what element and event you're trying to select it from. We need more information

Comment: Unless you give us more info, *here's your answer* $("a")

Comment: It's *well-worth* your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, maybe two, and it repays you that time *immediately*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the span's `id` a an anchor point, and use a [*descendant combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) to find the `a` within it:

```
var theLink = $("#guiaAtencion\\:ot4 a");
```

**Example**:

```js
$("#guiaAtencion\\:ot4 a").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<span id="guiaAtencion:ot4">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.apps.com">link</a>
  </p>
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or

```
var theLink = $("[id='guiaAtencion:ot4'] a");
```

**Example**:

```js
$("[id='guiaAtencion:ot4'] a").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<span id="guiaAtencion:ot4">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.apps.com">link</a>
  </p>
</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: It's invalid to put `p` elements inside `span` elements. The content model of a [`span`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (e.g., what it's allowed to have inside it) is [*phrasing content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but [`p`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements can only be used where [*flow content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected.